# MySQL date reservation

Tags: mysql

I try to find a similar question but didn't find an exact one so I'll post mine:

I have 2 tables:

- room (room_id)
- room_reservation (room_id, date)

How can I return list of rooms that have at least 1 day free between 2 dates.

For example, if I have those rooms:

room_id 1, 2 & 3

then in room_reservation table, I have the following:

```
1 - 2012-07-22
1 - 2012-07-23
1 - 2012-07-24
1 - 2012-07-25
1 - 2012-07-26
2 - 2012-07-23
2 - 2012-07-24
```

then doing a search for available room between 2012-07-22 and 2012-07-26 should return only room #2 and #3.

I have this query so far but didn't work... please help!

```
SELECT DISTINCT room_id AS id
FROM room
WHERE (SELECT COUNT('listing') FROM listing_calendar WHERE listing = l.listing_id AND date BETWEEN '2012-07-22' AND '2012-07-26' GROUP BY listing) < 5"
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this solution:

```
SELECT    a.room_id
FROM      rooms a
LEFT JOIN room_reservations b ON 
          a.room_id = b.room_id AND
          b.date BETWEEN '2012-07-22' AND '2012-07-26'
GROUP BY  a.room_id
HAVING    COUNT(b.room_id) < DATEDIFF('2012-07-26', '2012-07-22') + 1
```

---

### [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2904/3/0)